# Inserting objects from vector into binary tree

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search-tree

So I've got a BST.cpp and BST.h
and i've go a create and insert function

```
BST::node* BST::createLeaf(int value)
{
    node* newNode = new node;
    newNode -> value = value;

    //make sure left and right are pointing to null
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

void BST::insert(int value, node * Ptr)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = createLeaf(value);
    }

    //if tree is not empty
    else if (value < Ptr->value)
    {
        //go left, but check if it's pointing to something first
        if (Ptr->left != NULL)
        {
            //if yes, recursively move down the left side
            insert(value, Ptr->left);
        }
        //else if it's not pointing to anything
        else
        {
            //add mode tree
            Ptr->left = createLeaf(value);
        }
    }
```

I want to read in a .txt file with 10 numbers in it, store it in a vector and then put the numbers into the binary tree.

```
{
    vector<int> numbers;

    //Create an input file stream
    ifstream in("treeValues.txt",ios::in);


    int number;

    //Read number using the extraction (>>) operator
    while (in >> number) {
        //Add the number to the end of the array
        numbers.push_back(number);
    }

    //Close the file stream
    in.close();

    //Display the numbers to test
    cout << "Numbers:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }

    //add these numbers to the tree

    for (int i = 0; i <numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        myTree.insert(numbers[i]);
    }


    cin.get(); //Keep program open until "enter" is pressed

}
```

It doesn't work so I was wondering what the problem was? Is there another way to store the read in integers from the file into the node? Do I even need the vector?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what is not working? Is it the reading part or the binary tree?

Comment: No, I did a test to print out the contents of the tree in order traversal and threw in an 'else' for when the tree is empty and I keep getting that the tree is empty

Comment: You can only insert elements lower than the root element. This is not correct since your missing values bigger than your root element. Also you do not need a createLeaf  method if you're only creating and initializing a object there. You should add a constructor to your Node class.

Comment: And you are having another bug: Imagine having 60 as root and 40 as left child and you want to add 50. Your could would add 50 as the left child of 40 which is wrong.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks!